# GRAV CMS TNTSearch title page override

Tags: php, yaml, twig, customization, grav

I'm trying to customize the "TNTSearch Search" string from the search.md page of the Plugin.

```
---
title: TNTSearch Search
---
```

Tried to put an override in my template folder and other stuff without success.

How can this be customized?

Answer (score 0):

Create file `/user/pages/search/search.md` and add your new title. E.g.:

```
---
title: My New Title
---
```

Update after chat:
When default `search_route: '/search'` has been changed in config of plugin, above folder must match the name of the route.

Eg. if route is defined as `search_route: '/mysearch'` the overriding file should be `/user/pages/mysearch/search.md`

Comment: Tried that too. No change to be seen. Also tried it with the folder name `tntsearch`.

Comment: Above will change the title of the tab in the browser. Or did you expect anything else?

Comment: Did not change the title in the browser either.

Comment: Above suggestion is tested and working fine in my fresh Grav 1.7.6 installation. Added fresh TNTSearch, no changes. 
Cache should not be an issue, but try `bin/grav cache` anyway.

Comment: Yeah, checked that too. CMS and Plugins are all newest versions.

Comment: When adding Markdown to `search/search.md`, does that show up above the search box?

Comment: No. Not title and breadcrumb show no change and adding contend not showing up. If i mess around with the override and do something stupid i get an parsing error from Grav, so the file is seen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229299/discussion-between-passerby-and-mike).

Comment: OK i got it. I changed the Search Page Route in the plugin configuration. So the override had to be in a folder not called by the plugin name "search" but by the changed route name.